# How to set specified post(s) on widget by Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress, and want to set specified post(s) on widget. How can I achieve that? There is not such widget by default. My wordpress version is 5.2.2.

I tried the recent posts widget. But it was not what I expected. I want to set just specified post, not all recent posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Posts in Sidebar](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-in-sidebar/) plugin.With this, you can set a specific post in the sidebar with their id.

Comment: A perfect answer! I got what I wanted. Thank you very much!